# Firebase Firestore and Cloud Functions - use data from collection that is different to collection used to trigger function

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app and am trying to send automated push notifications. The trigger will eventually come from Cloud Pub/Sub, but right now I am triggering the function by creating a new document in a collection as follows:

```
exports.reminderFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('notifications/{notification}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {...
```

The payload of the notification uses data from this collection as follows:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('reminders', {notification: {
        title: snapshot.data().number, 
        body: snapshot.data().test,
        clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        }
```

This works fine.

What I want to do is use data from a *different* collection in the notification payload. For this I need access to the current user ID so I can access their documents. I have read that it is simple when using realtime DB, but cannot work out how to do it for Firestore.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

Is there anyway to do this? Or is there a better way to send push notifications where the notification uses the current user's documents?

Comment: It's not in the event.  You will have to provide it in the document that changed.

Comment: What if no document changes? The trigger will be from pub/sub as such: 
          `functions.pubsub.topic('topic-name').onPublish((message) => {
  // ...`

Comment: You would have to provide the UID in the message payload.

Comment: Yes, but the UID is what I don't know how to get when using Firestore. For Realtime DB I could use `context.auth` but since there is no equivalent for Firestore, I can't see how I could access a specific user's documents

Comment: If the UID is not in the payload of the event anywhere, what you're trying to do is impossible.  As I said, for Firestore triggers, there is no auth info in the event context.

Comment: ok makes sense - any ideas on how I could achieve this type of push notification using Firestore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217181/discussion-between-mrharvey-and-doug-stevenson).